# Aside from RPC calls, what could be taking my App Engine Program so long

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to performance optimize a page load in GAE, and I'm a bit stumped what is taking so long to serve the page.

When I first got appstats running I found the page was calling about 500-600 RPC calls. I've now got that down to 3.

However, I'm still seeing a massive load of extra time in App Stats. Another page on my site (using the same django framework + templating) loads in about 60ms, doing a small query to a small data set.

Question is, what is this overhead, and where should I be looking for trouble points?

The data in the request has about 350 records, and about 30 properties per record. I'm cool with the data call itself taking the datastore api time, but it's the other time I'm confused about. The data does get stepped through a biggish iterator, and I've now used fetch on most of these requests to keep the RPC call down, and make sure things are in memory rather than being queried as they go.

Slow Request - Look at all the extra blue

[image: Slow Request]

Fast Request , RPC blue is matched against overall blue

[image: Fast Request]

EDIT

OK, so I have created a new model called FastModel, and copied the bare minimum items needed for the page to it, so it can load as quickly as possible, and it does make a big difference. Seems there are things on the Model that slow it all down. Will investigate further.

Comment: I'm getting something very similar on a Java-based request. 200-ish objects, RPC calls very quick, 1.8 seconds of extra 'nothing'. I have to work on something else today, but my next tasks will be to reduce the amount of objects to see if the time is proportional to the amount of objects. I've also downloaded a profiler which I'll try out. My current guess is that it relates to marshalling objects into JSON. Good luck.

Comment: I'm curious if you're using Java.  Reason being, if you're using Java and Eclipse, there is a speed tracer that is part of the GAE plugin for Eclipse.  I haven't used it yet but am wondering if its useful in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

Deserializing 350 records, especially large ones, takes a long time. That's probably what's taking up the bulk of your execution time.

Comment: Do you mean specific objects that are serialized as a property on the model, or the actual de-serialziation of the Model object itself? (these model objects do have serialized properties on them)

Comment: @ChrisBarry I mean the time it takes to deserialize the model entities themselves.